# c# how to derive data from 3 tables in one object list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggeling with nested classes. What I'm trying to do is derive a dataset from 3 related tables.
Here are the classes:

```
    public partial class Trades
{
    public Trades()
    {
        this.Executions = new HashSet<Executions>();
    }

    public int TradeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public int MarketParticipantId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TraderId { get; set; }
    public int OtherMarketParticipantId { get; set; }
    public tradeType TradeType { get; set; }
    public orderTypesType OrderType { get; set; }
    public tradingCapacityType TradingCapacity { get; set; }
    public organisedMarketPlaceIdentifier OrganisedMarketPlaceIdentifier { get; set; }
    public actionTypesType ActionType { get; set; }
    public string LinkedTransactionId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Executions> Executions { get; set; }
    public virtual MarketParticipants MarketParticipants { get; set; }
    public virtual MarketParticipants MarketParticipants1 { get; set; }
}

public partial class Executions
{
    public Executions()
    {
        this.ExecutionDetails = new HashSet<ExecutionDetails>();
    }

    public int ExecutionsId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string ContractId { get; set; }
    public string ContractName { get; set; }
    public contractTypeType ContractType { get; set; }
    public buySellIndicatorType Side { get; set; }
    public energyCommodityType Commodity { get; set; }
    public settlementMethodType SettlementMethod { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExecutionStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExecutionEndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionTime { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryPointsId { get; set; }
    public int TradeId { get; set; }

    public virtual DeliveryPoints DeliveryPoints { get; set; }
    public virtual Trades Trades { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExecutionDetails> ExecutionDetails { get; set; }
}
```

This piece of code give me back a data setin an IQueryable object.

```
public static IQueryable GedTrades(int mpId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        var context = new RemitEntities();

        var myTrades = context.Trades
                .Where(t => (t.MarketParticipantId == mpId))
                .Select(
                    t =>
                        new 
                        { 
                            MarketParticipantId = t.MarketParticipantId,
                            TraderId = t.TraderId,
                            OtherMarketParticipantId = t.OtherMarketParticipantId,
                            TradeType = t.TradeType,
                            OrderType = t.OrderType,
                            TradingCapacity = t.TradingCapacity,
                            OrganisedMarketPlaceIdentifier = t.OrganisedMarketPlaceIdentifier,
                            ActionType = t.ActionType,
                            LinkedTransactionId = t.LinkedTransactionId,
                            Executions = context.Executions
                            .Where(ex =>
                                    (((ex.TradeId == t.TradeId) && (ex.ExecutionStartDate >= startDate)) &&
                                        (ex.ExecutionEndDate < endDate)
                                    )
                            ).Select(ex =>
                                new 
                                {
                                    ContractId = ex.ContractId,
                                    ContractName = ex.ContractName,
                                    ContractType = ex.ContractType,
                                    Side = ex.Side,
                                    Commodity = ex.Commodity,
                                    SettlementMethod = ex.SettlementMethod,
                                    ExecutionStartDate = ex.ExecutionStartDate,
                                    ExecutionEndDate = ex.ExecutionEndDate,
                                    TransactionTime = ex.TransactionTime,
                                    DeliveryPointsId = ex.DeliveryPointsId,
                                    ExecutionDetails = context.ExecutionDetails
                                        .Where(ed => (ed.ExecutionsId == ex.ExecutionsId))
                                        .Select(
                                            ed =>
                                            new 
                                            {
                                                Uti = ed.Uti,
                                                DeliveryStartTime = ed.DeliveryStartTime,
                                                DeliveryEndTime = ed.DeliveryEndTime,
                                                Price = ed.Price,
                                                Currency = ed.Currency,
                                                Quantity = ed.Quantity,
                                                QuantityType = ed.QuantityType
                                            }
                                        )
                                }
                            )
                        }
                );

        return myTrades;
    }
```

What I realy like to achieve is to parse the data set to another object by e.g. a list object like List. 
How do I do that?

Comment: Do you get back an IQueryable or an IQueryable<T>? You can just call .ToList() on an IQueryable<T>, but whether you'd want to depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm getting back an IQueryable. What I trying is to convert  Trade objects to an output class objet for writing XML files. The schema of the ouput object class is differen, zo I want to build a mapping class. Since I do have more Trade's, I seems to be handy to gettng back an List object from the database and parse the containg Trade objects, one by one by e.g. a foreach loop.

Comment: IQueryables are enumerable. You should be able to foreach over one normally if that's all you want to do. If you want to iterate over `myTrades`, you should be able to just do `foreach(Trade trade in myTrades)`.

Comment: Hi Grant,
What do you suggets to receive a List<Trade> ?

Comment: If you really want a List<Trade>, all you have to do is call `.ToList()`at the end of your LINQ expression.

Comment: That will give me that nasty error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'

Comment: What happens if you put the names of your types after your `new`s? Use `new Trade() { MarketParticipantId = t.MarketParticipantId ... }` instead of the anonymous types.

Comment: that will give me a "The entity or complex type 'Pvned.RemitModel.Trades' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query." error